# What is the difference when we use array names instead of spread operator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

What is the difference if I use:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
var mainArray = (numbers.length > 1) ? numbers : '';
```

instead of this:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
var mainArray = (numbers.length > 1) ? [...numbers] : '';
```

Comment: the object reference.

Comment: `[...numbers]` will give you new array where `numbers` is just a reference to existing array.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since assigment of data structures points to the same space in memory, if you have two variables referencing the same array, altering one variable will alter the other. That is to say:

if `x = [1, 2, 3]`
and `y  = x`
then we say `x.push(5)` `y` will also have that 5 because they are pointing to the same instance. If you use `[...x]` you are creating a copy of x. It consumes O(n) memory, a new reference. So if x is altered, y will be uneffected.

spreads are clean and neat but they do have overhead. They will effect performance if used on a very large data set.

Answer (score 1):

The difference if you use:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
var mainArray = (numbers.length > 1) ? numbers : '';
//mainArray == numbers => true
```

Here it will assign reference of `numbers` to `mainArray`

instead of this:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
var mainArray = (numbers.length > 1) ? [...numbers] : '';
//mainArray == numbers => false
```

Here it will create new array from `numbers`'s elements and will assign it to `mainArray`

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator (`...`) spreads out an array into individual values instead of an array of values. As is shown in the below code snippet `numbers` is an array of integers while `...numbers` is 3 separate integers. So `[...numbers]` will give you a new array with the same values and `numbers` is just a reference to the existing array.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(numbers);
console.log(...numbers);
```